# No Connection Could be made because the target machine actively refused it : IP:80

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-binding

I run a few WCF services (separated into their own web directories) that all reside on the same machine. some of these services are accessed locally via machines on the internal network, and some externally via other servers over WAN.

It's just simple BasicHttpBinding.

Nothing of note has changed over the last week, yet in the last week i have been getting this message, and from different WCF services hitting that server.

Firewall I believe is not an issue. The change is sudden and seemingly random. These services have been operating without issue for 3-4 years.

Any Ideas?

One of the messages:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

The other messages I also get is there is no endpoint listening at xxxx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address of SOAP action. Please see InnerException for more details

When I tried to load it in a browser (http://IP/Service/service.svc), during one of these episodes, the page wouldnt load. Unfortunately I can't recall what the browser was displaying, but the strange this is after displaying an error message it then came good and voila up came the service reference page.

Windows 7
IIS
Advice appreciated.

[image: the bane of my existence]

web.config (pretty much out of the box, never really changed)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="bla"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to load the service in localhost, if it is working then do Telnet from the client machine to the hosting server

Comment: I forgot to mention it is intermittent. It will work for 20 minutes, then stop. This morning it worked for 5 hours before it happened.

Comment: I had similar issue before and it was because the IIS process consume too much memory so at some point the process get killed by the system. As i recall there is an option in IIS for auto start and process once it is down.